# Facebook Graph API Comment

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How long is the comment option avaliable for posts on the feed? Can you comment on every post or just on posts that are not older than a specified date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can comment on any post at any time. I know I've seen some that are at least a few months old and have been commented on.